.htaccess redirect everything to https or new vhost except letsencrypt?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/\.well\-known/?.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)kashtata\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)kashtata\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kashtata\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://guesthouse.house%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

I have the following .htaccess code. It is supposed to redirect http://example.com to https://NEWexample.com and https://example.com to https://NEWexample.com (ex. if some nerdy user decides to type explicitly https://example.com, instead of just example.com or has it as a bookmark). This should happen for everything except letsencrypt (as I need it to issue certificate for example.com so https:// works on it).
I added the well-known line which is supposed to service http://kashtata.com/.well-known whatever (letsencrypt) but instead it redirects to guesthouse.house with the same request uri that letsencrypt wants. Any idea what i am missing?
Using Apache 2.4.
